# Moving Xampp's htdocs folder to external USB 2.0 hard disk

Tags: xampp, hard-drive, htdocs

As I build many virtual webs on localhost and the data of htdocs folder is increasing everyday.
I want to move the htdocs folder to external hard disk, is it possible to do that?
I try editing httpd.conf file. But when I open localhost, it shows "Access forbidden!" "403 error".

```
Alias /bitnami/ "my-hardisk:/htdocs"
Alias /bitnami "my-hardisk:/htdocs"

<Directory "my-hardisk:/htdocs">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am using xampp on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not work in Xampp.. If you want to maintain like this use any licensed linux OS and do install apache, php, mysql there you can create alias and use many sites from any folder..

Otherwise take backup of your htdocs and mysql/data and uninstall xampp then add additional Hard disk with GB you need then again reinstall xampp in that drive and replace the backup files..

Answer (score -2):

with XAMPP you can only access files from XAMPP directory>htdocs if you want to move htdocs folder in external hard drive then you have to reinstall XAMPP in the external hard drive. 
for reference :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4plJssbmro